# How do Rabbonim know where graves are located?

Tags: cemetery-grave

There is an (or more than one) [organization](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/article.php?p=129318) whose job is to ensure that Jewish graves aren't desecrated when construction companies do digs.

How do they know that there are graves there? Archeologists?

Moreover, how do they know that the cemetery is Jewish?

Comment: Btw, my edit is my suggested answer. (No source, ironically.)

Comment: @msh210, I haven't heard of these organizations outside of Israel. On the other hand, cemeteries in Europe are of much more recent origin and are generally well defined.